# Kotlin @Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function

Tags: kotlin

I have an issue with MyApp function, `content` value is unresolved and for `ContactContent()` shows this error: `@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function`

```
@Composable
fun MyApp(navigateToProfile: (Contact) -> Unit){
    Scaffold {
        content = {
            ContactContent(navigateToProfile = navigateToProfile)
        }
    }
}
```

**ContactContent Snippet**

```
@Composable
fun ContactContent(navigateToProfile: (Contact) -> Unit) {
    val contacts = remember { DataProvider.contactList }
    LazyColumn(
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 8.dp),
    ) {
        items(
            items = contacts,
            itemContent = {
                ContactListItem(contact = it, navigateToProfile)
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: show ur `ContactConent()`

Comment: I have added it @jorieitomuke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already in a `Scaffold`'s body. You don't need to use `content = {}`

Change to:

```
@Composable
fun MyApp(navigateToProfile: (Contact) -> Unit){
    Scaffold {
        ContactContent(navigateToProfile = navigateToProfile)
    }
}
```

`content` is a parameter of `Scaffold` If you want to use it:

```
@Composable
fun MyApp(navigateToProfile: (Contact) -> Unit){
    Scaffold(
        content = {
            ContactContent(navigateToProfile = navigateToProfile)
        }
    )
}
```

both work the same way.